# How to correcly upgrade your OpenMP version?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mpi, openmp

I'm trying to deploy an OpenMP/MPI project on some virtual machines through Amazon EC2. Every VM is running Ubuntu 16.04 and currently I have:
`gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609` and relative `mpich`.

I correctly tested my project on Ubuntu 18.04 with  `gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0`. Basically I'm using OpenMP array reductions with custom reduction operators and to my knowledge this became available since OpenMP 4.5. This indeed is a problem since on my VMs I get the following error: `error: ‘array1_test’ has invalid type for ‘reduction’`.

I thought I simple upgrade would suffice ([following this](https://tuxamito.com/wiki/index.php/Installing_newer_GCC_versions_in_Ubuntu)) but after that MPI was complaining with `Please use the same version of GCC and g++ for compiling MPICH and user MPI programs`. I tried reinstalling mpich but with no success.

I'm using cmake to compile. Linking MPI is done as following:

```
link_libraries(${MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES})
if(MPI_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS)
  set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS "${MPI_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
endif()
if(MPI_CXX_LINK_FLAGS)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS "${MPI_CXX_LINK_FLAGS}")
endif()
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I correctly upgrade OpenMP without messing up the MPI configuration?

Comment: You have to upgrade your compiler to a version that supports the OpenMP features you want to use. If MPI stuff uses a different compiler, that would have to be upgraded too to match.

Comment: As I said I've already tried upgrading ```gcc``` to version 7.4.0. ```mpicc``` is updated as well since it's linked to it. I'm still getting the MPI error sadly.

Comment: That error message sure sounds like something in the MPI toolchain wasn't upgraded.

Comment: I tried reinstalling mpich but it's no use either apparently.. Maybe it's worth to mention I'm using ```cmake``` to compile. I've updated the question.

Comment: The problem is that Ubuntu 16.04 packages (including MPICH) are compiled with a too old version of GCC. Using a newer version of GCC is not sufficient to fix the problem. Using a newer version of Ubuntu, like the LTS 18.04, should solve your problem. However, you can try to use [backport](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) so that MPICH and GCC could be up to date! Another alternative is to build MPICH yourself from a newer GCC ([Spack](https://spack.readthedocs.io) can help). Do not forget to also check CMake uses the same version between gcc and g++ as it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to stick to the old 16.04?

Comment: Yes I'm using ```starcluster``` to deploy on AWS and the latest compatible Ubuntu version is the 16.04.
I'll try your suggestions @JérômeRichard

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone experiencing my problem, I've solved the issue building from source MPICH as suggested by @Jérôme Richard.

1) I've installed a newer version of `gcc` in order to have a compatible OpenMP standard for my project (e.g. 4.5) and solve the `error: ‘array1_test’ has invalid type for ‘reduction’` issue.

2) I've downloaded the source files from MPICH website ([download section](https://www.mpich.org/downloads/)).

3) Following their installation guide I've managed to install `mpich` compiling with `gcc 7.4.0` to solve the `Please use the same version of GCC and g++ for compiling MPICH and user MPI programs` issue.

Please note that I needed to stick to Ubuntu 16.04. All this trouble can be skipped by just using a newer Ubuntu release (e.g. >=18.04).